# Android AndEngine Tower of Hanoi pop "Game Over" when rings reach 3rd tower

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0, andengine, towers-of-hanoi

I am unable to successfully output a "Game Over!" when the rings reach the 3rd tower. May I ask your opinion as to how to do this?

I followed the tutorials of "http://www.raywenderlich.com/12065/how-to-create-a-simple-android-game" which doesn't include a "Game Over" in it and I'm finding it hard to add one since I'm new to android programming.

```
private void checkForCollisionsWithTowers(Ring ring) {
    Stack<Ring> stack = null;
    Sprite tower = null;

    if(ring.collidesWith(mTower1) && (mStack1.size() == 0 || ring.getmWeight() < mStack1.peek().getmWeight())) {
        stack = mStack1;
        tower = mTower1;
    } else if(ring.collidesWith(mTower2) && (mStack2.size() == 0 || ring.getmWeight() < mStack2.peek().getmWeight())) {
        stack = mStack2;
        tower = mTower2;
    } else if(ring.collidesWith(mTower3) && (mStack3.size() == 0 || ring.getmWeight() < mStack3.peek().getmWeight())) {
        stack = mStack3;
        tower = mTower3;

    } else {
        stack = ring.getmStack();
        tower = ring.getmTower();
    }

    ring.getmStack().remove(ring);
    if(stack != null && tower !=null && stack.size() == 0) {
        ring.setPosition(tower.getX() + tower.getWidth()/2 - ring.getWidth()/2, tower.getY() + tower.getHeight() - ring.getHeight());
    } else if(stack != null && tower !=null && stack.size() > 0) {
        ring.setPosition(tower.getX() + tower.getWidth()/2 - ring.getWidth()/2, stack.peek().getY() - ring.getHeight());
    }

    stack.add(ring);
    ring.setmStack(stack);
    ring.setmTower(tower);
}
```

}

Comment: Contact that blogger.

Comment: check weather stack3 is filled or not.If the stack size is 3 then call game over screen for tower3.you can  check this condition in "checkForCollisionsWithTowers()" method. check every time when this metod being called.Implement convenient code  at last lines of that method.

Comment: else if(ring.collidesWith(mTower3) && (mStack3.size() == 0 || ring.getmWeight() < mStack3.peek().getmWeight())) {
        stack = mStack3;
        tower = mTower3;

I changed (mStack3.size() == 3) then applied finish(); to test if it works but the application closes once i place a ring in the 3rd tower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void checkForCollisionsWithTowers(Ring ring) {
        Stack<Ring> stack = null;
        Sprite tower = null;
        if (ring.collidesWith(mTower1) && (mStack1.size() == 0 || ring.getmWeight() < ((Ring) mStack1.peek()).getmWeight())) {
            stack = mStack1;
            tower = mTower1;
        } else if (ring.collidesWith(mTower2) && (mStack2.size() == 0 || ring.getmWeight() < ((Ring) mStack2.peek()).getmWeight())) {
            stack = mStack2;
            tower = mTower2;
        } else if (ring.collidesWith(mTower3) && (mStack3.size() == 0 || ring.getmWeight() < ((Ring) mStack3.peek()).getmWeight())) {
            stack = mStack3;
            tower = mTower3;
        } else {
            stack = ring.getmStack();
            tower = ring.getmTower();
        }
        ring.getmStack().remove(ring);
        if (stack != null && tower !=null && stack.size() == 0) {
            ring.setPosition(tower.getX() + tower.getWidth()/2 - ring.getWidth()/2, tower.getY() + tower.getHeight() - ring.getHeight());
        } else if (stack != null && tower !=null && stack.size() > 0) {
            ring.setPosition(tower.getX() + tower.getWidth()/2 - ring.getWidth()/2, ((Ring) stack.peek()).getY() - ring.getHeight());
        }
        stack.add(ring);
        ring.setmStack(stack);
        ring.setmTower(tower);

        isGameOver();
    }

    private void isGameOver() {
        if(mStack3.size() == 3){


             Font main_font = FontFactory.create(this.getFontManager(), this.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, BitmapTextureFormat.RGBA_8888, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA, Typeface.DEFAULT, 60, true, Color.BLACK_ABGR_PACKED_INT);
             main_font.load();

             Text gameOverText = new Text(0, 0, main_font, "GameOver", this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
             gameOverText.setPosition(CAMERA_WIDTH/2 - gameOverText.getWidth()/2, CAMERA_HEIGHT/2 - gameOverText.getHeight()/2);
             scene.attachChild(gameOverText);

             scene.clearTouchAreas();


       }

        }
```

Comment: What imports are needed to run this part of the code?

Scene.attachChild(gameOverText); Scene.clearTouchAreas();

Comment: :I added final Scene scene = new Scene(); which removes the problem regarding 

scene.attachChild(gameOverText);

             scene.clearTouchAreas();

which makes the application run but when all three rings are on the 3rd tower, nothing happens.

Comment: no need to create new object for Scene. Make existing scene to global i.e in onCreateScene() method.

Comment: I already have

 protected Scene onCreateScene() {
  final Scene scene = new Scene();

in the oncreatescene but private void isGameOver() doesn't seem to recognize it. @Rama

Comment: remove final for scene and make it global. and  Private method  for isGameOver() can access from same class.

Comment: So I removed final from Scene, now it's labeled as "Scene scene = new Scene();"

    scene.attachChild(gameOverText);

             scene.clearTouchAreas();

scene still displays as cannot be resolved.

Comment: make scene variable  as a global  variable.

Comment: Thank you! It finally works! Now I just need to add a button for retry or exit.. Thanks